# revealing two text elements from behind a line

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the right way to animate two text elements so that it seems they're revealing from behind a line?

One from above and another one from the bottom.

Here is a code:

```js
//pause the animation at first
document.getElementById("tutorialText").classList.add("paused");
document.getElementById("tutorialSubText").classList.add("paused");

//after 3 seconds initiate the animation
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("tutorialText").classList.add("played");
  document.getElementById("tutorialSubText").classList.add("played");

}, 3000)
```

```css
html{
 overflow:hidden;
}


.mainTexts{
 position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 7.5vw;
    color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    left: 18.5vw;
    top: 15vh;
    animation: rollUp 0.5s ease-out ;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.subTexts{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 3vw;
    color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
    left: 20vw;
    top: 40vh;
    animation: rollDown 0.5s ease-out ;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 60vh;

}

@-webkit-keyframes rollUp {
   from { top: 55vh }
   to   { top: 0vh }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rollDown {
   from { top: -45vh }
   to   { top: 60vh }
}

.paused {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important; 
}

.played {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: running !important; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body>

<div>
 <p id="tutorialText" class="mainTexts">Tutorial</p>

</div>
<hr/>
<div >
 <p id="tutorialSubText" class="subTexts">Learn a new sentence</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `overflow:hidden` from their container. aside , `flex` to center the whole thing, and coordonates to size text `p` from `div` container can also help. you can drop the `vw/vh` values for the slide and use percentage.

one way to do it :

```js
//pause the animation at first
document.getElementById("tutorialText").classList.add("paused");
document.getElementById("tutorialSubText").classList.add("paused");

//after 3 seconds initiate the animation
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("tutorialText").classList.add("played");
  document.getElementById("tutorialSubText").classList.add("played");

}, 3000)
```

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;/* settings preparing to center content*/
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  margin: auto 5vw;/* one way for flex child  vertical centering */
}

.mainTexts {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 7.5vw;
  color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  top: 0;/* size them via coordonates related to the relative parent */
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  animation: rollUp 0.5s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.subTexts {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  animation: rollDown 0.5s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rollUp {
  from {
    top: 150%
  }
  to {
    top: 0vh
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rollDown {
  from {
    top: -150%
  }
  to {
    top: 0
  }
}

.paused {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important;
}

.played {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running !important;
}

body{
  background: black
}

div {/* size parents and make them reference */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 7.5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <p id="tutorialText" class="mainTexts">Tutorial</p>

  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <p id="tutorialSubText" class="subTexts">Learn a new sentence</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```