# How to limit the visibility of a text to a container?

Tags: html, css

How can we make a text that is only visible to a rectangle? (think of the rectangle like a container, the text is only visible when it is right in the rectangle)

Then I want to animate the text from bottom to above like this:

[image]

Then:

[image]

and finally:

[image]

Here is the animation code but I have no idea how can we limit the visibility of the text to a container:

**Note: I only can use viewport units like `vw` and `vh` and absolute positions**

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Text {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 7.5vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0vh;
  animation: rollUp 3s ease-out infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}


@-webkit-keyframes rollUp {
  from {
    top: 150vh
  }
  to {
    top: 0vh
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body>

<div >
 <p id="Text">Revealing Text</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what did you not understand here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059451/revealing-two-text-elements-from-behind-a-line/59059705#59059705 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your container element a fixed height and set `overflow: hidden`.

You will also need to use `position: relative` so that the text is positioned relative to the container element.

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Text {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 7.5vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0vh;
  animation: rollUp 3s ease-out infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}


@-webkit-keyframes rollUp {
  from {
    top: 150vh
  }
  to {
    top: 0vh
  }
}

.container {
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px dashed orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
 <p id="Text">Revealing Text</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...plus one... the closest one till now... but I only can use viewport units like vw and vh and absolute positions as I mentioned

Answer (score 3):

You need `overflow: hidden` on the `<p>`

Answer (score 3):

similar to your other question : [revealing two text elements from behind a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059451/revealing-two-text-elements-from-behind-a-line/59059705#59059705)

- the text container is sized via vw like font-size from the text.
- overflow is used to hide the text
- position: relative is used for the absolute child , so it uses the parent area to move up and down and % can be used instead vw/vh units

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Text {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 7.5vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0vh;
  animation: rollUp 3s ease-out infinite alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}
div.ov {position:relative;overflow:hidden; height : 8.5vw;}

@-webkit-keyframes rollUp {
  from {
    top: 150%
  }
  to {
    top: 0%
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body>

<div class="ov">
 <p id="Text">Revealing Text</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer...I'll accept that answer but I only can use viewport units like vw and vh and absolute positions as I mentioned...

Comment: vw unit do not need to be used for the animation, but where is the text supposed to stand ? where do you want the text to appear and stop sliding is where the edge of the div contaniner is supposed to be ;) . can you sketch this , so we can adapt div position and div size .

Comment: The problem is I want to use this as an iFrame inside the page that has been created using Articulate Storyline ... So I need to prevent the iFrame content from moving or zooming on page zoom... I need to make every position absolute and every units to vw and vh

Answer (score 2):

Use clip-path with a translation:

```css
#Text {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  animation: rollUp 3s ease-out;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,  100% 100%,0 100%);
}


@keyframes rollUp {
  from {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,  100% 0   ,0 0);
  transform:translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="Text">Revealing Text</p>
```

Comment: thanks but I want to animate the text, not the container... this way the text is fixed ...

Comment: @SaraRee check the update, I am animating the text. I have no container in my code